# Показывает что нету ссылки на объект ,хотя она есть

Tags: c#, unity3d

привязываю объект с информацией об игре к другому объекту на сцене , в визуалке ошибок нету при запуске начинает каждый кадр строчить что нету ссылки на объект.

```
    public class CubeSingularity : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Lerp=1;
    public static bool singbool=false;
    public Text needforsing;
    public Text lvlTEXT;
    public Image line;
    public GameObject LootPanel;
    public bool IsLootPanel = false;

    public GameData gamedata;


    private void Update()
    {
        LVL();
        LerpVoid();

    }

   public void LerpVoid()
   {
     if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) & gamedata.gamedata.Score > 0 & (gamedata.gamedata.Score - Lerp > 0 ) & singbool==true)
       {
         Lerp += Lerp*0.01f;
            gamedata.gamedata.Score -= Lerp;
          gamedata.gamedata.SInfo.NowSingularityExp += Lerp;
      }
       else
       {
           Lerp = 1;
   }

  }

    public void LVL()
    {
        line.fillAmount = gamedata.gamedata.SInfo.NowSingularityExp/ gamedata.gamedata.SInfo.NeedSingularityExp;
        lvlTEXT.text = "lvl: "+gamedata.gamedata.SInfo.SingularityLvl;
        needforsing.text = Mathf.Round(gamedata.gamedata.SInfo.NowSingularityExp) + " / " + Mathf.Round(gamedata.gamedata.SInfo.NeedSingularityExp);
        if (gamedata.gamedata.SInfo.NowSingularityExp >= gamedata.gamedata.SInfo.NeedSingularityExp)
        {
            gamedata.gamedata.SInfo.SingularityLvl += 1;
            gamedata.gamedata.SInfo.NowSingularityExp = 0;
            gamedata.gamedata.SInfo.NeedSingularityExp = Mathf.Round(100 * Mathf.Pow(1.15f, gamedata.gamedata.SInfo.SingularityLvl));
            IsLootPanel = true;
            LootPanel.SetActive(true);
            singbool = false;
        }
    }


    [Serializable]public class SingularityInfo
    {
        //Информация Чёрной дыры
        public float NowSingularityExp;
        public float NeedSingularityExp;
        public int SingularityLvl;

        public SingularityInfo()
        {
           NowSingularityExp=0f;
           NeedSingularityExp = 100f;
           SingularityLvl = 0;
        }

    }

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажу 44 строчку этого скрипта, там проблема, тут не разберешь где 44

Comment: Не нужно помечать в заголовке ответа его статус. Если вопрос, который вы задали, оказался неактуален и не был отвечен, вы можете его удалить. Если хотите поделиться опытом с другими разработчиками, можете опубликовать подробный ответ и спустя 2 дня после задания вопроса его принять как решение.

Answer (score -2):

Вопрос решён , на другом объекте из множеств лежал еще один такой компонент где я забыл привязать объект.